# How to increase the space (Data Space Total) used by Docker ? That value is less than half on the disk size

Tags: docker

Many times, I have this error when building Dockerfile :

**devmapper: Thin Pool has 157168 free data blocks which is less than minimum required 163840 free data blocks. Create more free space in thin pool or use dm.min_free_space option to change behavior**

My disk has at all 250Go and when I execute docker version, I can see in storage part :

```
Storage Driver: devicemapper
 Pool Name: docker-253:0-19468577-pool
 Pool Blocksize: 65.54kB
 Base Device Size: 21.47GB
 Backing Filesystem: xfs
 Data file: /dev/loop0
 Metadata file: /dev/loop1
 Data Space Used: 97.03GB
 Data Space Total: 107.4GB
 Data Space Available: 10.35GB
 Metadata Space Used: 83.67MB
 Metadata Space Total: 2.147GB
 Metadata Space Available: 2.064GB
 Thin Pool Minimum Free Space: 10.74GB
 Udev Sync Supported: true
 Deferred Removal Enabled: false
 Deferred Deletion Enabled: false
 Deferred Deleted Device Count: 0
 Data loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data
 Metadata loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata
 Library Version: 1.02.135-RHEL7 (2016-11-16)
```

I tried after stopping docker service : 
I tried :

```
dockerd --storage-opt dm.thinpooldev dm.min_free_space=3%
dockerd --storage-opt  dm.thinp_autoextend_percent
```

But those command doesn't succed.

How to increase the Data Space Total (the free space on the disk is more than 2 times 107.4GB) ? 
Or How to decrease the Thin Pool Minimum Free Space: 10.74GB ?

Comment: Did you find how to increased the space?

Comment: Dimitri, check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you've cleaned/pruned and still have issues this is how you actually modify the min space setting.

Create/Modify this file: **/etc/docker/daemon.json**

```
{
   "storage-opts": [
    "dm.min_free_space=1%"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Make sure to stop and start docker.
Also, create a backup copy if needed (cp -au /var/lib/docker /var/lib/docker.backup)
1. sudo systemctl stop docker
2. Create/Modify this file: /etc/docker/daemon.json (as you said)
3. sudo systemctl restart docker

Answer (score -2):

> **DISCLAIMER**: This answer does not address the specific question of the poster.
> However it may help or alleviate the problem to people that get the
> same error message.
>
> This answer specifies the way to generally free space, not configuring the amount of space to be used.

Probably it's because of docker occupying its assigned space with containers, images or volumes.
To see actual Docker's usage, run:

```
$ docker system df

TYPE                TOTAL               ACTIVE              SIZE             RECLAIMABLE
Images              135                 27                  41.33GB             33.77GB (81%)
Containers          34                  32                  509.4MB             15.21kB (0%)
Local Volumes       387                 3                   3.706GB             3.706GB (99%)
```

[Prune](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune) helps with cleaning up:

```
$ docker system prune
WARNING! This will remove:
    - all stopped containers
    - all networks not used by at least one container
    - all dangling images
    - all build cache
Are you sure you want to continue? [y/N] y
```

(See alternatives in Prune page for older Docker versions).

Beware that volumes are not removed by default, to prevent loss of data. You'd have to specify it yourself, adding `--volumes` or cleaning them manually.

Comment: this answer seems like you didnt understand what was being asked, please review and edit your answer if needed

Comment: You are right. My answer is just showing how to free space, not how to change the space settings. In my case, I got rid of that problem by freeing space, but it's not what the OP is asking.
Answer should be deleted then, but I don't see how I can do that.

Comment: You should edit your answer with a visible disclaimer regarding the answers offerings, though it you want to delete - at the bottom of your answer you have share, edit, delete